# Get a list of all scripts loaded via importScripts

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In a non-worker context, we can use `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` to get a list of all scripts on the page, and determine the URL for a given script.

Within a `Worker`, is there any way to get a list of the scripts imported via `importScripts`?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting question.  Obivously, there is no DOM for a Worker.  I don't see any type of interface on `WorkerGlobalScope` for listing the scripts unless you can find them in [`WorkerGlobalScope.caches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/caches).

Comment: @jfriend00 the `caches` is empty. It seems like the contents of the script is  evaluated, after which the reference to the script is discarded.